# Keycloak returns 500 / NPE URI in Spring on Docker container

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose, keycloak, http-status-code-500

I have a problem with Keycloak on my Ubuntu server. Register and login works fine. But when I try to make any request to the spring application by user bearer token, keycloak returns me 500 - Internal server error in Swagger. *(Everything on localhost works fine!)*

Logs of application when I try to make any request by bearer token:

```
dictionary_app_prod               | java.lang.NullPointerException: null
dictionary_app_prod               |     at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3042) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
dictionary_app_prod               |     at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
dictionary_app_prod               |     at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:850) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
dictionary_app_prod               |     at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:66) ~[httpclient-4.5.8.jar!/:4.5.8]
dictionary_app_prod               |     at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.JWKPublicKeyLocator.sendRequest(JWKPublicKeyLocator.java:97) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-4.8.3.Final.jar!/:4.8.3.Final]
dictionary_app_prod               |     at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.JWKPublicKeyLocator.getPublicKey(JWKPublicKeyLocator.java:63) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-4.8.3.Final.jar!/:4.8.3.Final]
dictionary_app_prod               |     at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.getPublicKey(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:121) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-4.8.3.Final.jar!/:4.8.3.Final]
dictionary_app_prod               |     at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.createVerifier(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:111) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-4.8.3.Final.jar!/:4.8.3.Final]
dictionary_app_prod               |     at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.verifyToken(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:47) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-4.8.3.Final.jar!/:4.8.3.Final]
dictionary_app_prod               |     at org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.authenticateToken(BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.java:103) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-4.8.3.Final.jar!/:4.8.3.Final]
dictionary_app_prod               |     at org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.authenticate(BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.java:88) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-4.8.3.Final.jar!/:4.8.3.Final]
```

My docker-compose file:

```
volumes:
  mysql-data:
    driver: local
  mysql-log:
    driver: local
  mysql-conf:
    driver: local
  postgres_data:
    driver: local
  mysql_data:
    driver: local

services:
  dictionary_app_prod:
    container_name: dictionary_app_prod
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8888:8082
    depends_on:
      - "dictionary_app_prod_mysql_test" # This service depends on mysql. Start that first.
      - "dictionary_app_prod_mongo"
      - "dictionary_app_prod_keycloak"
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://dictionary_app_prod_mysql_test:3306/general?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
      SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI: mongodb://springboot-mongo:27017/mongodb
  dictionary_app_prod_mysql_test:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - "mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "mysql-log:/var/log/mysql"
      - "mysql-conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d"
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: general
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
  dictionary_app_prod_mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: springboot-mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - $HOME/data/springboot-mongo-data:/data/db
      - $HOME/data/springboot-mongo-bkp:/data/bkp
    restart: always
  dictionary_app_prod_keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: MYSQL
      DB_ADDR: dictionary_app_prod_mysql_test
      DB_DATABASE: general
      DB_USER: root
      DB_PASSWORD: root
      KEYCLOAK_USER: test
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: test
      # Uncomment the line below if you want to specify JDBC parameters. The parameter below is just an example, and it shouldn't be used in production without knowledge. It is highly recommended that you read the MySQL JDBC driver documentation in order to use it.
      JDBC_PARAMS: "useSSL=false"
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - dictionary_app_prod_mysql_test
```

Keycloak config:

```
import org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakConfigResolver;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakSecurityComponents;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
        basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class,
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.management.HttpSessionManager"))
@EnableWebSecurity
class KeycloakConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                //.antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                //.antMatchers("/library/**").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://dictionary_app_prod_keycloak:8080/auth
keycloak.realm=SpringBootKeycloak
keycloak.resource=login-app
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=true
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I just decided to install Keycloak directly on server without using Docker. Everything works great now.